# nodejs npm install discord.js not working on debian 9

Tags: node.js, npm, debian

nodejs npm install discord.js not working on debian 9
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19WPl.png**strong text**

Comment: Do you have node-gyp installed globally on your machine? Try to run: sudo npm install -g node-gyp.

Comment: I tried the same error

Comment: Try to install discord.js with sudo